# How to debug Laravel application using PhpStorm

Tags: php, laravel, debugging, phpstorm, xdebug

I'm developing a Laravel 8.6 application using PHP 8.1 with Xdebug extension but I can't get the PhpStorm's debugging tool to work.

Here's my debug configuration. Notice that I'm using a virtual host

[image]

PhpStorm's is listening for PHP debug connections and I set a breakpoint to an endpoint but when I make the http request via Postman nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

php.ini

```
zend_extension=C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_host = "api-fitplanner.localhost"
xdebug.remote_autostart=on
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_port=9003
```

Comment: Can you show your XDEBUG Settings from `php.ini`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Xdebug 2 settings, but you are running Xdebug 3.1.3. Please refer to the [upgrade guide](https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide) on how to convert these.

From what you wrote above, it should be:

```
zend_extension=C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll
xdebug.mode=develop,debug
xdebug.client_host="api-fitplanner.localhost"
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
```

Comment: As I suspected :)

Comment: do you know if it's possible to configure the debugger to only show variable values and its relationship values? currently it shows me bunch of other values which I'm not really interested and it's hard to keep track of the variable. https://i.postimg.cc/DZcGszkp/Screenshot-2022-02-25-131815.png

Comment: I don't know @shAkur whether PhpStorm allows you to filter our certain properties. Xdebug itself does not. But I don't know which ones you're interested in, and which ones not.